# TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function with angularJs and angus

Tags: angularjs, select, jquery-plugins

i'm having some hard time figuring out what does not works with angular select plugin.

I'm working in a project where the codebase is huge and works well, and the imports are managed with angus, so i have a file in which are declared all css, scripts and so on, and for developing reasons, i'm adding some new pages and views to software.

As I said, for developing reason, i have to add my plugins and css directly in my view, and not in the angus build tool, so i'm pretty sure there is only 1 instance of jquery (avoiding this [bug](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-extras/issues/308)).

problem is that when i try to add a simple select in my view like that :

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-select">Esempio opzioni</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="180px" id="example-select">
            <option>Opzione 01</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="example-select">Esempio opzioni</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" disabled data-width="180px" id="example-select">
            <option>Opzione 01</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style:'form-control',
    showTick:true
}); 
$('.selectpicker').defaults('val','');  
</script>
```

with imports like these:

```
<link href="somepath/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <script src="somepathjquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="somepath/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="somepath/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="somepath/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script> 


<!-- Bootstrap - DatePicker -->
<link href="somepath/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src=somepath/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="somepath/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap - Select -->
<link href="somepath/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="somepath/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="somepath/bootstrap-select/js/i18n/defaults-it_IT.min.js"></script>
```

I get these errors :

```
TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

and :

```
defaults-it_IT.min.js?_=1501583424550:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'defaults' of undefined
```

note that all links are correct, just different cause security reasons, and the jquery is commented

any clue?

EDIT: 
Because someone asked that, in the build tool used by all the application, jquery is referenced in this order (pseudo-code):

```
'jquery.js',
'angular/angular.js',
'bootstrap/bootstrap.js'
```

Comment: use this code after document loaded  $(document).ready(function(){ $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({:'form-control', showTick:true});})

Comment: @KARANLAGALWAR Unexpected token :

Comment: @VED had answered right you had not added jquery script in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can be the potential reson for the error:

1. I don't see reference of Jquery .
2. If you have added jquery reference make sure you add it before bootstrap:

E.g:

```
<script src="path to jquery.js"/>
<script src="bootstrap.js"/>
```

Comment: jquery is referenced in the build file used by all the software, in this order
'jquery.js',
 'angular/angular.js',
  'bootstrap/bootstrap.js',

Comment: @Anon the only reason for error is here, Jquery is not refrenced. Just make sure you have the refernce available.